# how to clear the previous contents of the table layout?

Tags: android

I have created a table layout in xml. At runtime, i am using a condition where in first case i am filling table layout. However in second case i am again adding contents to the same layout. And they get added up at the end of layout. However i need to clear the previous contents of layout. 
I can use these removeallview() method,It doesn't work.. my code as

```
ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {

        table=new TableLayout(mContext);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams=  new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int leftMargin=0;
        int topMargin=0;
        int rightMargin=0;
        int bottomMargin=0;
        tableParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        table.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

        lf_header = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        header_view = lf_header.inflate(R.layout.header, null); 

        DBAdapter dbAdapter=DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
        try {
            dbAdapter.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
        }
        dbAdapter.openDataBase();
        if(i==0){
            ((TextView) header_view.findViewById(R.id.header_txt1)).setText("Over Due");
            header_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            table.addView(header_view);
ll.addView(table);
```

Any suggestions ??

example code is appreciate..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `table.removeAllViewsInLayout()`

```
int count=table.getChildCount();
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
             table.removeView(layout.getChildAt(i));
```

Comment: when click "ALL" button this table layout created.after I'm click another button and again I will click "ALL" button.ple suggest where I will removed or whr to use  table.removeAllViewsInLayout()?

Comment: when you need to remove just call it